# handle clicks on submenus in android

Tags: android, submenu

I am new to android and stuck at the point where i have to detect clicks on submenus that are defined in XML file

my XML file is :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ccard_menu1"
        android:title="Select from Profile?"
        ></item>

    <item android:id="@+id/ccard_menu2"
        android:title="Add Field"
        >

        <menu >
            <item android:id="@+id/submenu1"
                android:title="Add Products"
                ></item>
            <item android:id="@+id/submenu2"
                android:title="Add Clients"
                ></item>

            <item android:id="@+id/submenu3"
                android:title="Add a Custom Field">s</item>

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

how do i detect clicks on "submenu 1,2,3"  in onOptionsItemSelected method?

how do i have to structure the switch case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you are looking for something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.submenu1:
            // do something
            return true;
        case R.id.submenu2:
            //do something else
            return true;

            // etc..
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Please correct me if I am mistaken.